# could not be able to work with setKeyListener in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I have placed a button in EditText, I have set the button invisible at starting code of main XML is:

```
RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/search_prompt"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:background="@drawable/search"
        android:onClick="loadWeather" android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want that the Button only be visible if there is some text in EditText if EditText is empty the Button should not be visible a have set a setKeyListener listener on EditText in following way:::

```
final Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    myEditText.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public boolean onKeyUp(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!myEditText.getText().equals("")){
                searchButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onKeyOther(View arg0, Editable arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onKeyDown(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public int getInputType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public void clearMetaKeyState(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

It makes Button invisible at starting, but now I'm no more able to enter any text in EditText, EditText does not get any input through keyboard. Please tell mo how to get rid of this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count,      int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        if( count == 0){
            searchButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }  else{
            searchButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Log.v(TAG, "afterTextChanged");
    }
});
```

Comment: This code gives me a NullPointerException on first line where addTextChangedListener is added. help please..

Comment: Maybe you forgot to get `myEditText` or `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`, where in your_layout declared EditText with `android:id="@+id/editText1"`

Comment: Yes Man your are right I forget that! now it works, but when I click Backspace the Button gets Invisible even if there is some text in EditText!

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer and modified `if(count == 0)` to  `if(count == 0 && myEditText.getText().length() == 0)` so that works accordingly.